# math domain error

Tags: python-3.x, математика

```
import math
 print ('рассчитаем горизонтальный цилиндрический танк')
 L = float(input('Введи длину: '))
 dm = float(input('Введи диаметр(В миллиметрах): '))/1000
 r = dm/2
 print('Зная, что диаметр равен:',dm,',то радиус будет равен',r,".")
 rseg = float(input('Введи радиус сегментов на концах: '))
 a = int(input('Введи ребро кубического цилиндра (в сантиметрах): '))/100
 zapem1 = int(input('На сколько (процентов) заполнить горизонтальный цилиндрический танк: '))/100
 zapem2 = int(input('На сколько процентов заполнить кубический танк: '))/100
 PI = float(input('Число PI: '))
 D = round((2*rseg),2)
print (D ,' - диаметр сегмента')
print ('Теперь, рассчитаем объём этой ёмкости')
print('Найдём длинну усечённого конуса')
 luscon = round((math.sqrt((D-L)**2 - ((D-L)/2)**2)),3)
print('Длинна усечённого конуса равна : ',luscon,' метров' )
 Vuscon = round(((PI * luscon *(r**2 + (r*rseg) + rseg**2))/3),2)
print('Объём усечённого конуса равен: ',Vuscon)
 Vcil = round((PI * r**2 * L),2)
print ('Объём цилиндра = ',Vcil)
 Vfig = round((Vcil + 2*Vuscon),2)
print('Объём фигуры равен: ', Vfig)
print('Рассчитаем объём молока в цилиндре')
 Vmc = round((Vfig * zapem1),2)
print (Vmc , ' - Объём молока в цилиндре.')
print ('Теперь найдём площадь заполненного')
 Spc = round((r**2 * (math.acos(1-((dm-L)/2))-(L-r))*(math.sqrt((dm)*(dm-L) - (dm-L)**2))),2)
print (Spc,' - Площадь заполненного')
print('Рассчитаем для кубиической ёмкости')
 Vkub = a**3
print (a,' - объём куба')
print ('Найдём высоту куба')
 Vkm = zapem2 * Vkub
 hkub = round((Vkm/a**2),2)
print (hkub , ' - высота куба')
print ('Ответы :')
print (Vkm,' - объём молока в кубе')
print (hkub , ' - высота куба')
print (Vmc , ' - Объём молока в цилиндре.')
```

Что хочу сказать ,после ввода переменных , при компиляции пишет "math error domain". Строка :

```
 Spc = round((r**2 * (math.acos(1-((dm-L)/2))-(L-r))*(math.sqrt((dm)*(dm-L) - (dm-L)**2))),2)
```

Comment: Ну посчитайте вручную - может, для вводимых вами данных выход ха пределы области определения, или вообще формула не та...

Comment: Или sqrt из отрицательного числа, или acos из больше 1.